# How to pass data from UITableView to parent class?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, delegates

i've got 2 classes: `List <UITableViewDelegate` and `TableView <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource`.

Class `TableView` is custom class of UITableView which get data to app by Core Data and it's work. Object `tableView` is initialized in `List` Class and this object has `delegate` and `dataSource = self`.

Question is: How can i send data from `tableView` object by selecting row to `List` class with my own function or something like that?

in `tableView` i use delegate function:
`-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i solved it.

i'm beginner in obj-c developer so i don't know that i can create second delegate for my class but with other name (other than 'delegate'). when i create it and add some methods, it works great.